# Wordpress home address in magento is giving 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento2, fishpig

I have integrated **WordPress** into my **Magento 2** application using **Fishpig**. I have changed WordPress home address as `sitename/m4blog`.

In my local `http:localhost/sitename/m4blog` is working fine. But when I deployed same thing to server, then getting 404 error. In server the url is `https://sitename/m4blog`. I have checked the perma links settings. Beow Permalinks settings it is like this

> If your `.htaccess` file was writable, we could do this
>   automatically, but it isn’t so these are the `mod_rewrite` rules you
>   should have in your `.htaccess` file. Click in the field and press
>   CTRL + a to select all.

After this there is code for .htaccess. So I replaced my `.htaccess` in server with  this code . But no use. Could anybody help me out to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**First way**

1. Set your WordPress setup folder name "wp".
2. M2 Admin Menu > WordPress > Path = wp
3. Database: magento2_wp > Table: wp_options

option_id = 1
option_name = siteurl
option_value = http://www.example.com/wp //Folder name of your WordPress installation.
autoupload = yes

option_id = 2
option_name = home
option_value = http://www.example.com/blog //Frontend URL
autoupload = yes

**Second Way**

- Go to wordpress folder most probably inside root.
- edit .htaccess and paste a code you display on admin
- Save it.

Comment: check your file permission

Comment: .htaccess has 664 permission

Comment: make it 777 for now

Comment: Changed to 777, but no use